# parsed data can't save to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

the json data is

```
"{\"n925D\":1,\"t925D\":23.5,\"h925D\":3276.8,...
```

I'm replacing the symbol by

```
var results = post
    .replace(/\{/g, '[[')
    .replace(/\"/g, '\'')
    .replace(/\,/g, '\'],[')
    .replace(/\:/g, ',\'')
    .replace(/\}/g, '\']]')
    .replace(/\\([^u])/g, '$1')
;
```

console.log(results); shows

```
[['n925D','1'],['t925D','23.5'],['h925D','3276.8'],...
```

console.log(query.sql); shows

```
INSERT INTO table (did,val) SET '[[\'n925D\',\'1\'],[\'t925D\',\'23.5\'],[\'h925D\',\'3276.8\'],
```

how can I remove the `\` actually...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing extra characters before inserting data in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049506/removing-extra-characters-before-inserting-data-in-mysql)

Comment: using stripslashes come with this error ... /node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

Comment: even try results.replace(new RegExp("\\\\", "g"), "") and results.replace(/\\(.)/mg, "$1") ,,,, no help

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably parse JSON (or XML or HTML) with regexes. Instead, [parse it, change the data, and re-emit it](https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/nodejs-parse-json/).

```
var jsonData = '{\"n925D\":1,\"t925D\":23.5,\"h925D\":3276.8,...';

// Parse it into a hash
var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData); 

// Change the hash in jsonParsed to an array of arrays.

// Convert it back into JSON
jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

Comment: delete the replace method and adding var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(post);  come with this error... /node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

Comment: done, by separate replace(/\\([^u])/g, '$1'), thanks all